# How to get the path from a file URL?

Tags: java, regex, indexing, substring

I have Strings in this format :

```
file://c:/Users/....
file://E:/Windows/....
file:///f:/temp/....
file:///H:/something/....
```

How can I get just `c:/Users/...` or `H:/something/...` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tested and will replace an arbitrary number of slashes.

```
String path = yourString.replaceFirst("file:/*", "");
```

And if you only want it to match two or three slashes

```
String path = yourString.replaceFirst("file:/{2,3}", "");
```

Comment: The `[]` are redundant. Also, `///?` is shorter and simpler than `/{2,3}`.

Answer (score 1):

```
String path = new java.net.URI(fileUrl).getPath();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can replace the string "file://" in your string with nothing:

```
String path = yourString.replace("file://", "");
```

Comment: And what if it contains 3 slashes like `file:///` ?

Comment: the above answer will not satisfy  file:///f:/temp/.... file:///H:/something/....

Comment: `String path = yourString.replaceFirst("^file:///?", "");` - There is no method `String.replace(String, String)`.

Comment: @Christoffer Hammarström : what about `file://c/Users`

Answer (score 0):

What about that?

```
String path = yourString.replaceFirst("file:[/]*", "");
```